# How to implement outer product of two vectors in Scheme?

Tags: matrix, vector, scheme

I want to define a function in Scheme that will compute the outer product of two vectors.

for example:

```scm
(outerProduct '(1 2 3) '(4 5))
```

the output is supposed to be the following matrix:

```scm
((4 5) (8 10) (12 15))
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Note that collections used in your example aren't vectors, but lists. But this code with two nested [`for/list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Flist%29%29)s will work for both:

```
(define (outer-product v1 v2)
  (for/list ((e1 v1))
    (for/list ((e2 v2))
      (* e1 e2))))
```

Examples:

```
> (outer-product '(1 2 3) '(4 5))
'((4 5) (8 10) (12 15))

> (outer-product (vector 1 2 3) (vector 4 5))
'((4 5) (8 10) (12 15))
```

Comment: Heh, just noticed this question wasn't tagged racket. Hope OP is using it, because I included a Racket-specific way in my answer too.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the OP meant 'vectors' in the mathematical sense, not in terms of the data structure being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `map` if you don't want to use Racket-specific constructs (Assuming you're working with lists like in your code and not vectors like the subject line (Maybe you're thinking of vectors in the math sense, not the scheme sense?); though Racket has a `vector-map` too so it's easy to adapt:

```lisp
(define (outerProduct l1 l2)
  (map (lambda (x) (map (lambda (y) (* x y)) l2)) l1))
```

Example:

```lisp
> (outerProduct '(1 2 3) '(4 5))
'((4 5) (8 10) (12 15))
```

Or using the [`math/matrix` library](https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/matrices.html) that comes with Racket:

```lisp
(require math/matrix)
(define (outerProduct l1 l2)
  (let ((m1 (->col-matrix l1))
        (m2 (->row-matrix l2)))
    (matrix->list* (matrix* m1 m2))))
```

(This is a better option if you use its matrix type directly instead of converting to and from lists and are also doing other stuff with the values; also the docs suggest using typed Racket for best performance)

Answer (score 0):

```
(define outerprod
  (lambda (a b)
    (map (lambda (a)
           (map (lambda(b) (* a b))
                b))
         a )))


1 ]=> (outerprod '(1 2 3) '(4 5))
;Value: ((4 5) (8 10) (12 15))
```